# Using Ext4 partitions on external storage

Tags: permissions, usb-drive, external-hdd, ext4, ownership

If I want to use a USB flash memory or an external hard disk to transfer data and at the same time I want to use ext4 partitions on them. How could I do that without getting problems regarding permissions and ownership? How could I use it as I would if I were using NTFS partitions; without having to change permissions or ownership every time I plug it in a computer?

Note:
I understand that I won't be able to access these partitions from Windows, but I want to be able to access them from any Linux machine without having to change permission or ownership. I know that I won't face any problems if the other machines's user ID is the same as mine; but for instance, Fedora's first user has the ID 500 and Ubuntu's first user has the ID of 1000, which means that if I was transferring data from an Ubuntu machine to a Fedora machine, I'll either have to change permissions or I'll have to change ownership. Which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it currently.  I keep meaning to patch the kernel ext4 driver to accept the uid/gid options like fat, ntfs, and udf, but just never seem to get around to it.